# Should I ask a question about a site with particular functions I am looking for? (Not just like "what's your favorite one?")

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, scope

I am looking for particular site/platform where I want to post/share some of my ideas/concepts related to the IT area and where I can get responses/discussion on them, but strictly related to IT and even IT programming.

The thing is I am not asking 'what sites would you recommend?' or 'what are your favorite ones?'. I am just asking 'if any of them exist?' as I don't know if they even do (as any mentioned in my question lack some of the part).

[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755611/collaborative-blog-web-site-to-share-ideas-and-get-their-evaluations-responses) is pretty direct with clear criteria:

- site to share ideas;
- to get feedbacks on those ideas (as discussions);
- IT (programming (soft)) specific;
- rather not related to any specific framework or technology (like Java or .NET);
- with an ability to post by any user (even as a beginner) (but not only the site's authors);

(I don't get what's the difference between this one and for instance the following one: *[how to parse markdown via C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304693/how-to-parse-markdown-via-c-sharp)* as I am asking not for what 'tools' is the best, I just don't even know which 'tools' exist for my request).

So,

- Should I ask such questions on Stack Overflow?
- Should I just rephrase it in some other way?
- If not, then where can I ask such ones at all?

Comment: In short: no, no, and chat (or some other place in the Internet).

Comment: Oh, thank a lot, dude! I've just forgotten about 'some other place in the Internet!' Will check there, for sure! Is it right next to 'any button' button?

Comment: Agat, you notice the irony? You're asking for a recommendation for an external resource. Even here, that's off-topic. This is a site for discussing Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange. We don't do recommendations for other sites. (And it's not like there aren't thousands of IT forums out there that would gladly give you tons of suggestions if you tried.)

Comment: Irony? Yep. I have pretty good experience in that 'Art'. ;)
But the problem here is none answers to me that 'questions about any other sites are strictly forbidden' (do they? github? jekyll? google?). I only see here: 'bla-bla-bla ... your question is "opinion based"'. But none can answer why is it different from at least this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304693/how-to-parse-markdown-via-c-sharp. Someone asks there "how to?" and gets an answer: "with using such ... tools". I am asking here: where I can share and be responed, but instead... "you question is opinion based"

Comment: And the thing is even not in off- or "on-" topic. I've been really trying to find some such site for a long time. And tried to post it here because I do usually (and successfully) use stackoverflow for getting answers. So, why would I need stackoverflow at all if it does not help?

Comment: StackOverflow is meant for help with programming, it's not an ask-all site for any topic you can think off.

Comment: Absolutely. But my question is exactly programming related (to developers community), as I want to share my idea about some of MVC concepts and get community response. I would not be looking for some site where I would want to ask 'Please, help me evaluate if my cat would become a suburb princes!'

Comment: Anyway, is there any stackExchange site I can ask such questions? And what's about presenting my idea on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @Agat presenting ideas and general discussion and feedback are not only topic on SO or Programmers.  You need to have a specific question and need a specific answer.  No matter how you try to phrase it, unless you have a specific problem, it won't be on topic anywhere.

Comment: Ok. I've got that. Concepts discussions is not a Stockexchange purpose. No questions.

Comment: I am voting to close this question as off-topic as it concerns only one specific site on the Stack Exchange network. See: [Why are questions only about one site in the network considered off-topic here?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355783)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is [Slashdot.org](http://Slashdot.org). I don't speak Russian, but thanks to Google Translate, I was able to recognize the editorial format that Slashdot uses.

That being said. I totally agree with the closure of your question.

StackOverflow is about solving specific work problems (at least, that's my own interpretation of their rules).

> - Should I ask such questions on stackoverflow?
> - Should I just rephrase it in some other way?
> - If not, then where can I ask such ones at all?

To put it bluntly:

No, no, and we don't know.

If you happen to not be satisfied with the limited purpose of StackOverflow, it's your burden to find another site that will satisfy that need, it's certainly not ours.

Comment: Well, I am not sure what makes you think that I needed some Russian-speaking site, as if I wanted, I would just already used habrahabr. But thanks for your answer and referencing slashdot.

Comment: Slashdot is a US site hosted in English. It's not Russian. I just meant to say that I used Google Translate to translate habrahabr and found it remarkably similar in content and in format to a site I already knew which is called Slashdot.

Comment: Actually, it's still far not the same. habrahabr covers any area of IT: starting from iPhone finishing with .NET. (While I can not even find 'software' section on slashdot). That's actually looks pretty weird that there is no any similar alternatives around the world(!) to that site. (Not sure if that deals somehow with... you know... national mentality, but still).

Answer (score 4):

I was about to create a post for you but got held up with other tasks.
I'll use this opportunity to clarify myself here as well.

The reason I believe your question was offtopic is because of this rule:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam

Your question specifically asks for a recommendation of a website, whereas the question you deem similar asks how something can be achieved. I think it's worth saying that this question is in poor quality as well considering it does not show any effort and should it have been posted now I would vote for a close as well. But even regardless of that: it leaves room for a code solution and not solely asking for an external resource.

To answer your concrete questions:

> Should I ask such questions on stackoverflow?

No, see above.

> Should I just rephrase it in some other way?

No, your question at its essence is asking for an external resource which is against the rules.

The last one I'll leave to others, since I suggested you ask this here.

Comment: 'does not show any effort'? Really? I guess, the only clear answer of the community is 'I just don't know' instead.

Comment: I've spent about an hour of reviewing and exploring different sites in the web. So, if some person just don't know if something exists, that does not mean that another one hadn't been looking for that for some time.

Comment: I was referring to the question about 'Markdown in C#'. But yes, even for your question it can be said that it shows very few effort. It doesn't take a whole lot of time to say 'I've been looking for an hour'. What we want to see is the results of that search: what have you come across and what didn't work about it. Do note that this is for actual on-topic questions, not for tool recommendations.

Comment: Well, those -- just words... I've already provided my **efforts** describing the sites which have just partial functionality needed. That's even becoming funnier looking to millions of 'a-la-from-india questions' like 'my batton is not press! help!' and still flowing on on the site.

Comment: Anyway, that has no sense to debate with companies... You have your own vision -- and good luck to you with that! Please, don't spend much more time to convince myself that I am a fat lazy instance. I surely am. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Asking if a site exists would result in exactly the same kind of answers as asking for everyone's favorite, so no, that would not be on topic on Stack Exchange sites.  You can ask in a chat room related to the topic area you're curious about.

Comment: Hm... What can be the 'topic area' for such type of a question?

Answer (score 1):

I frankly don't see the difference between *what sites would you recommend?* and *is there a site providing this service?*

Both are asking to recommend a site, which is not a suitable question for SO.

---

> Should I ask such questions on stackoverflow?

No, such questions are off-topic on SO

> Should I just rephrase it in some other way?

No, see above

> If not, then where can I ask such ones at all?

Not on SO. As proposed in the comments, you can try with the chat.