# Different fonts on close reason popup

Tags: bug, design, close-dialog, fonts

There're different fonts for items in the list on the popup for closing a question with "A community-specific reason":

> [image]

Comment: No bug. Some items have title, and some don't, and each "type" has its own design. When there is title, it is bold and the body with smaller font, which I find rather good.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars looks like the first two should have their own titles as well.

Comment: That would make it consistent, however will also clutter the already big popup, with something that isn't really required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason some close reasons have small text is because they have been updated to use the new format, which includes a "brief description" (bigger text) in addition to "usage guidance" (smaller text).

Apparently there are some active discussions about changing the rest, such as [Let's update our blatantly off-topic close reason to use the 5 available close fields!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371518/323179).