# Empty text field next to light bulb on questions closed with multiple community-specific (off-topic) reasons

Tags: bug, design, off-topic, post-notices

It seems that recently, a bug was introduced in the post notice on questions that were closed with multiple community-specific (off-topic) close reasons. There's a spot for a text field next to a light bulb, but no text in that field (a blank space):

[image: Empty text field in close notice]

This wasn't an issue until recently. As an example, earlier this year, the notice has no such empty block:

[image: No empty lightbulb]

I suspect (though cannot confirm) that this was as a result of the recent change to show full close reason descriptions to everyone and not just the author and users with close vote privileges.

For context, a community-specific close reason (off-topic sub-reason) [shows up in the close notice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339401/377214) if at least two users vote for it, meaning it's possible for a question to be closed with two reasons if 2-3 users or a moderator vote for one reason and two other users vote for a second reason. It's also possible (but extremely rare) for there to be three reasons, if two users vote for one sub-reason, two other users vote for another, and a moderator then bindingly closes with a third.

While we're at it, it would be nice if the [issue report the second screenshot above was a part of](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375415/377214) was fixed.

Comment: Looks like the post notice with multiple close reasons was not (fully/properly) updated when [this change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/379011/348196) was implemented. The "Closed [...] by [...]" text (along with the icon in front of it) should be moved to the bottom, right above the last line. Then, the close reasons should be next to the light bulb icon just like what happens when there's only one reason.

Comment: Heh, noticed this but figured it may have been an odd thing with my browser at the time.

Comment: Just encountered this for this question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392530/why-wont-stack-overflow-let-me-save-edits-to-my-own-posting